# How to push content in real time in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, real-time, server-sent-events, observers

I'm wondering the way to push content in my site in real time..
I've researched some time and I realized that there are many ways to do this work.

Some considerations first:
I have a Rails 3 App with some social functionality..one of the features I want to achieve is to notify my users when a new activity is created.
My first approach was to implement [SSE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) and a controller that searches in the DB for new registries after the last loaded activity.

This can work but this requires too many DB queries when all I need is to push the activity to all active users (related with that activity) when a new activity is created, without the need to do DB queries..

My second approach was to create a route pointing to a controller and an observer to catch when an new activity is created, later pass the current activity created to the controller and finally render the activity partial through SSE.

Here comes my problem..  how can  connect the observer with the controller and pass it the current activity to be rendered?
And there, can I use another controller type such as a Metal Controller or even an Abstract one?

In this point I realized that could be another approach to do this job..
It'd be really nice if I could find a way to do this without having to develop it in another language or framework.. I think that should have a gem that could do real time apps easier..
What do you think?? I'm on the right way or what I should do to achieve this??
Many Thanks!!

Comment: This is often achieved using an external service such as [Pusher](http://pusher.com/). There's quite [a few great tutorials](http://pusher.com/tutorials) for a quick overview.

Comment: Another option for self-hosting is [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) ([RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)).

Comment: Yet another option: https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut.  Even though it's deprecated it's still solid code!

Comment: I've added a good option below "Rails 3.0+ Push Content in Real-time with PubNub" and that will likely be the #1 most easiest method available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Rails 3.0+ Push Content in Real-time with PubNub

In order to safely and securely push real-time updates to your users with some social functionality on your web site or web app there are, as you say, many options available and many nuances to consider with this as well.  **There is a gem for this!**  And I will help you get started by providing a simple start guide here for your Rails 3.0+ app and web site.  First you'll want to run `gem install pubnub` which is the real-time component known as PubNub that will allow you to send notifications directly to targeted users or a group of users on your website and apps.  This allows you to target only those who are online and interested in receiving the notifications from your Rails server.  You can consider this as efficient server-sent events that require no DB Lookup or other resource intensive operations on your servers.

### Ruby GEM Install

```
gem install pubnub
```

#### Require PubNub GEM

```
require 'pubnub'
```

#### Initialize The PubNub Class

```
pubnub = Pubnub.new(
    :publish_key   => 'demo', # publish_key only required if publishing.
    :subscribe_key => 'demo', # required always
    :secret_key    => nil,    # optional - message signing
    :cipher_key    => nil,    # optional - AES 256 Crypto
    :ssl           => true    # optional - SSL 2048bit
)
```

#### From Rails 3.0+ Send Messages to the Web App

Now from your Rails App with the `pubnub` class ready, you can send any kind of JSON data type including a String, Number, Array and Dictionary/Object:

- a "String"
- a Number 123
- an array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
- an object { :a => "apple" }

The following code will show you the process which will pass a message from your Rails App directly to the browser or web app that you users are running.  Essentially sending the data to your users when you need to directly from your server.  The `pubnub.publish(...)` function will serialize the message you send as a JSON for transport to your mobile and web apps.

```
## Broadcast or Unicast to Browser App User(s)
pubnub.publish(
    :channel  => "event_feed_channel",
    :message  => { :event => "update", :from => "Jay", :feed => "New Updates!" },
    :callback => lambda { |info| puts info }
)
```

This process works great for performance and security considerations and never requires DB queries; saving you from hammering on your Database server and other resource intensive operations.  You may consider this process as **SSE (Server-Sent Events)** while you are using the PubNub GEM in your Rails applications.

Using the PubNub GEM you are essentially *sending events* from your Server direct to your User's Browser/App.  It removes the need for client-side periodic AJAX requests.  This is because you are only sending data to your user's when new information is available.  You may also [consider using more PubNub Real-time Network features like Presence and Storage/Playback](http://www.pubnub.com) by visiting the home site to learn more details about the Ruby features.  And also [use the Developers Dev Console](http://www.pubnub.com/console) for debugging if needed during your integration into your Rails code.

#### Setup Browser to Receive Server-Sent Events

Next you need to setup your app to receive the Server-Sent Events by running init and passing in the

```
<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.4.2.min.js ></script>
<script>(function(){

    // Class Setup
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({ subscribe_key : 'demo' });

    // Event Hook Setup
    pubnub.subscribe({
        channel : "event_feed_channel",
        message : function(m){ pubnub.events.fire( m.event, m ) }
    });

    // RECEIVE the "update" Server Broadcast Event in the Browser
    pubnub.events.bind( "update", function(message) {
        console.log( "update a <div> with received event: ", m );
    } );

})();</script>
```

> Note you may be interested in [Advanced Subscribe Connectivity Options and Events](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript#advanced-subscribe-connectivity-optionscallbacks).

Notice how the `"update"` event is identical to the `:event => "update"` message value in the **ruby** code.  This means that the event will be triggered based on the name you supply and you need to bind the event to trigger code to execute on your Web App page.  Inside this triggered event you will update the User Interface with any relevant details that the user would want to see on their screen in real-time.

Also notice the `:channel  => "event_feed_channel"` is the `publish` channel, and this must be identical as the `subscribe` channel in the JavaScript client code.

If you want to read the source code of the Ruby GEM, it is available via [GitHub PubNub Ruby-based APIs](https://github.com/pubnub/ruby).

These are the basics for getting started with Ruby 3.0+ Apps and sending events directly from your server to your End-users.  Note this also works for Mobile Apps that run on iOS Web Browsers or Android Browsers.  Also old versions of IE are supported for this mechanism.  In addition you could optionally consider server sent events from your Rails servers directly to Native iOS applications and Native Android Applications.  If you have any questions ask them here on this Forum.

Comment: Thanks @PubNub! It worked as expected..Only a suggestion that can do your gem more powerful..add some built-in rendering functionality, I think is a common task that every coder must do, it'll do your gem more complete and powerful and the coders will thank you a lot..

If someone need to know how to use partials o render html using existing views from inside a model (I had to do it that way), I used [Render Anywhere Gem](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere). It worked pretty well and the implementation is quite easy.

Comment: I have another question @PubNub, in my application there is a following functionality between users.. How can I publish messages **only** to the followers users of a particular user? I guess that there are many ways to achive this, but what is the best one? Many thanks!

Comment: Use Multiplexing and publish to the `"secret-user-id"` channel that each user owns individually.  For example you would subscribe to the `"group-channel,secret-user-id-channel"` channels.  Notice the `,` comma which separates the names of the channels.

Comment: Nice solution, but not really suitable if you plan to sell your software on premise.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a [realtime rails gem](http://mikeatlas.github.io/realtime-rails/) and a sample realtime server (node.js) which enables easy realtime messaging without the need of a paid, third party, such as Pusher or PubNub. It works with Rails 3+.